# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Tags: java, android, exception, arraylist

The title is the error i've been receiving when I try (I think) to add an object to an arraylist

Here is the start of my code up to the onCreate method. I'm trying to use a button to add an object of "TimeTableEntries" to the "timetableItemsList" arraylist

```
*import statements*

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
TimetableEntriesClass timetableEntry;
private static final int Add_New_Item = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int Remove_Item = Menu.FIRST + 1;

private boolean addingNew = false;
private ListView timetableListView;
private EditText moduleCodeText;
private EditText DayOfWeekText;
private EditText StartTimeText;
private EditText DurationText;
private EditText SessionTypeText;
private EditText RoomText;
private Button Add;
private ArrayList<TimetableEntriesClass> timetableItemsList;
private TimetableEntriesAdapter aa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    timetableListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    moduleCodeText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ModuleCode);
    DayOfWeekText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DayOfWeek);
    StartTimeText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.StartTime);
    DurationText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Duration);
    SessionTypeText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SessionType);
    RoomText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Room);
    Add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
    timetableItemsList = new ArrayList<TimetableEntriesClass>();
    int resID = R.layout.timetable_view;
    aa = new TimetableEntriesAdapter(this, resID, timetableItemsList);

    timetableListView.setAdapter(aa);

    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimetableEntriesClass item = new TimetableEntriesClass(moduleCodeText.getText().toString(), DayOfWeekText.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(StartTimeText.getText().toString() + ""), Integer.parseInt(DurationText.getText().toString() + ""),
                    SessionTypeText.getText().toString(), RoomText.getText().toString());

            timetableItemsList.add(item);
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

            moduleCodeText.setText("@string/module_code");
            DayOfWeekText.setText("@string/day_of_week");
            StartTimeText.setText("@string/start_time");
            DurationText.setText("@string/duration");
            SessionTypeText.setText("@string/type_of_session");
            RoomText.setText("@string/room");

        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(timetableListView);
}

04-04 15:19:11.499 2082-2119/com.example.daniel.mobileassignment E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xad2fefd0
04-04 15:19:13.523 2082-2082/com.example.daniel.mobileassignment W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
04-04 15:19:13.532 2082-2082/com.example.daniel.mobileassignment D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-04 15:19:13.547 2082-2082/com.example.daniel.mobileassignment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.daniel.mobileassignment, PID: 2082
                                                                               android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                                                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
```

Comment: What parameters does the constructor of `TimetableEntriesAdapter` expect?

Comment: @helleye It takes String, String, Int, int, String, String

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here to find that but it might be something like this?

Comment: are you calling getString anywhere in there?

Comment: I am in prepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: No, I didn't ask for `TimetableEntriesClass`. I asked for `TimetableEntriesAdapter`

Comment: @helleye here's the constructor here:   public TimetableEntriesAdapter(Context _context,
                           int _resource,
                                   List<TimetableEntriesClass> _items) 
    {
        super(_context, _resource, _items);
        resource = _resource;
    }

Comment: Ok, so it is not inside the constructor itself. Is this the complete stack trace? It seems it doesn't have all the information. Can you check and update the stack trace if necessary?

Comment: @helleye I found the problem, it was the setText in my ArrayAdapter, it was looking for a String resource ID when it just needed an int!

Comment: Good that you found it. Usually the issue is like that. But you didn't post ArrayAdapter source code, nor full stack trace, otherwise we would have helped you much sooner :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was the setText in my ArrayAdapter, it was looking for a String resource ID when it just needed an int!